# Optimizing a Python Function of SmoothStep with Multiple Conditionals for Numba Vectorization

Tags: python, numpy, performance, vectorization, numba

I implemented a function which creates a smooth rectangle function using [SmoothStep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep):

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, njit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

@njit
def GenSmoothStep( vX: np.ndarray, lowVal: float, highVal: float, vY: np.ndarray, rollOffWidth: float = 0.1 ):
    
    lowClip  = max(lowVal - rollOffWidth, 0)
    highClip = min(highVal + rollOffWidth, 1)

    for ii in range(vX.size):
        valX = vX.flat[ii]
        if valX < lowClip:
            vY.flat[ii] = 0.0
        elif valX < lowVal:
            # Smoothstep [lowClip, lowVal]
            valXN = (lowVal - valX) / (lowVal - lowClip)
            vY.flat[ii] = 1 - (valXN * valXN * (3 - (2 * valXN)))
        elif valX > highClip:
            vY.flat[ii] = 0.0
        elif valX > highVal:
            # Smoothstep [highVal, highClip]
            valXN = (valX - highVal) / (highClip - highVal)
            vY.flat[ii] = 1 - (valXN * valXN * (3 - (2 * valXN)))
        else:
            vY.flat[ii] = 1.0

numGridPts = 1000

lowVal  = 0.15
highVal = 0.75
rollOffWidth = 0.3

vX = np.linspace(0, 1, numGridPts)
vY = np.empty_like(vX)

GenSmoothStep(vX, lowVal, highVal, vY, rollOffWidth = rollOffWidth)

plt.plot(vX, vY)
```

The function includes several conditionals which implies a vectorization unfriendliness.
I was wondering if there are some simple steps to make the function more Numba friendly.

#### Update

I took the code by @AndrejKesely and updated it to handle the edge cases in my code (`lowVal = 0.0` and / or `highVal = 1.0`).
I also add a variant to clip without branches.
This is the current state:

```py
# %% 

import numpy as np
from numba import jit, njit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from timeit import timeit

@njit
def GenSmoothStep000( vX: np.ndarray, lowVal: float, highVal: float, vY: np.ndarray, rollOffWidth: float = 0.1 ):
    
    lowClip  = max(lowVal - rollOffWidth, 0)
    highClip = min(highVal + rollOffWidth, 1)

    for ii in range(vX.size):
        valX = vX.flat[ii]
        if valX < lowClip:
            vY.flat[ii] = 0.0
        elif valX < lowVal:
            # Smoothstep [lowClip, lowVal]
            valXN = (lowVal - valX) / (lowVal - lowClip)
            vY.flat[ii] = 1 - (valXN * valXN * (3 - (2 * valXN)))
        elif valX > highClip:
            vY.flat[ii] = 0.0
        elif valX > highVal:
            # Smoothstep [highVal, highClip]
            valXN = (valX - highVal) / (highClip - highVal)
            vY.flat[ii] = 1 - (valXN * valXN * (3 - (2 * valXN)))
        else:
            vY.flat[ii] = 1.0

@njit
def Clamp001( x: float, lowBound: float = 0.0, highBound: float = 1.0 ):
    if x < lowBound:
        return lowBound
    if x > highBound:
        return highBound
    return x

@njit
def Clamp002( x: float, lowBound: float = 0.0, highBound: float = 1.0 ):
    return max(min(x, highBound), lowBound)


@njit
def SmoothStep001( x: float, lowBound: float = 0.0, highBound: float = 1.0 ):
    x = Clamp001((x - lowBound) / (highBound - lowBound), 0.0, 1.0)
    return x * x * (3.0 - 2.0 * x)

@njit
def SmoothStep002( x: float, lowBound: float = 0.0, highBound: float = 1.0 ):
    x = Clamp002((x - lowBound) / (highBound - lowBound), 0.0, 1.0)
    return x * x * (3.0 - 2.0 * x)

@njit
def GenSmoothStep001( vX: np.ndarray, lowVal: float, highVal: float, vY: np.ndarray, rollOffWidth: float = 0.1 ):
    lowClip  = max(lowVal - rollOffWidth, 0)
    highClip = min(highVal + rollOffWidth, 1)

    if (highVal == 1.0) and (lowVal == 0.0):
        for ii in range(vX.size):
            vY[ii] = 1.0
    elif (highVal == 1.0):
        for ii in range(vX.size):
            vY[ii] = SmoothStep001(vX[ii], lowClip, lowVal)
    elif (lowVal == 0.0):
        for ii in range(vX.size):
            vY[ii] = 1 - SmoothStep001(vX[ii], highVal, highClip)
    else:
        for ii in range(vX.size):
            vY[ii] = SmoothStep001(vX[ii], lowClip, lowVal) * (1 - SmoothStep001(vX[ii], highVal, highClip))

@njit
def GenSmoothStep002( vX: np.ndarray, lowVal: float, highVal: float, vY: np.ndarray, rollOffWidth: float = 0.1 ):
    lowClip  = max(lowVal - rollOffWidth, 0)
    highClip = min(highVal + rollOffWidth, 1)

    if (highVal == 1.0) and (lowVal == 0.0):
        for ii in range(vX.size):
            vY[ii] = 1.0
    elif (highVal == 1.0):
        for ii in range(vX.size):
            vY[ii] = SmoothStep002(vX[ii], lowClip, lowVal)
    elif (lowVal == 0.0):
        for ii in range(vX.size):
            vY[ii] = 1 - SmoothStep002(vX[ii], highVal, highClip)
    else:
        for ii in range(vX.size):
            vY[ii] = SmoothStep002(vX[ii], lowClip, lowVal) * (1 - SmoothStep002(vX[ii], highVal, highClip))



# %%
# Validation + JIT Compilation
numGridPts = 10_000

lowVal  = 0.35
highVal = 0.55
rollOffWidth = 0.3

vX = np.linspace(0, 1, numGridPts)

hF, vHa = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 3, figsize = (16, 5))
vY = np.empty_like(vX)
GenSmoothStep000(vX, lowVal, highVal, vY, rollOffWidth = rollOffWidth)
vHa[0].plot(vX, vY)
vY = np.empty_like(vX)
GenSmoothStep001(vX, lowVal, highVal, vY, rollOffWidth = rollOffWidth)
vHa[1].plot(vX, vY)
vY = np.empty_like(vX)
GenSmoothStep002(vX, lowVal, highVal, vY, rollOffWidth = rollOffWidth)
vHa[2].plot(vX, vY);


# %%
# Check Performance

time000 = timeit("GenSmoothStep000(vX, lowVal, highVal, vY, rollOffWidth = rollOffWidth)", number = 10_000, globals = globals())
time001 = timeit("GenSmoothStep001(vX, lowVal, highVal, vY, rollOffWidth = rollOffWidth)", number = 10_000, globals = globals())
time002 = timeit("GenSmoothStep002(vX, lowVal, highVal, vY, rollOffWidth = rollOffWidth)", number = 10_000, globals = globals())

print(time000)
print(time001)
print(time002)
```

The output is (On my computer, `Intel Core i7-6800K`):

```py
0.23776450000877958
0.23713289998704568
0.23025239999697078
```

So it seems to be still very close.

Comment: Instead of writing your own smoothing function, try using `np.hanning` window, its numba-compatible. Split it in half and add as many ones in the middle as you want

Comment: By the way, should not exceeding the `highClip` lead to setting `1.0` ? `elif valX > highClip:
            vY.flat[ii] = 1.0`. That seems theoretically expected.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you just want to combine `smoothstep`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


@njit
def smoothstep(edge0, edge1, x):
    x = np.clip((x - edge0) / (edge1 - edge0), 0, 1)
    return x * x * (3.0 - 2.0 * x)


numGridPts = 1000

lowVal = 0.15
highVal = 0.75

vX = np.linspace(0, 1, numGridPts)
vY = smoothstep(0, lowVal, vX) * (1 - smoothstep(highVal, 1, vX))

plt.plot(vX, vY)
plt.show()
```

Shows this graph:

[image]

---

EDIT: New version (but in general the same like combining smoothsteps), without allocations and `if`-s (with `rollOffWidth` support):

```py
@njit
def clamp(x, lowerlimit=0.0, upperlimit=1.0):
    if x < lowerlimit:
        return lowerlimit
    if x > upperlimit:
        return upperlimit
    return x


@njit
def smoothstep(edge0, edge1, x):
    x = clamp((x - edge0) / (edge1 - edge0), 0, 1)
    return x * x * (3.0 - 2.0 * x)


@njit
def GenSmoothStep2(
    vX: np.ndarray,
    lowVal: float,
    highVal: float,
    vY: np.ndarray,
    rollOffWidth: float = 0.1,
):
    lowClip = max(lowVal - rollOffWidth, 0)
    highClip = min(highVal + rollOffWidth, 1)

    for i in range(len(vX)):
        vY[i] = smoothstep(lowClip, lowVal, vX[i]) * (
            1 - smoothstep(highVal, highClip, vX[i])
        )
```

---

Benchmark:

```py
numGridPts = 1000

lowVal = 0.45
highVal = 0.65
rollOffWidth = 0.3

vX = np.linspace(0, 1, numGridPts)
vY = np.empty_like(vX)

# warm up numba:
GenSmoothStep(vX, lowVal, highVal, vY, rollOffWidth=rollOffWidth)
GenSmoothStep2(vX, lowVal, highVal, vY, rollOffWidth=rollOffWidth)

from timeit import timeit

t1 = timeit(
    "GenSmoothStep(vX, lowVal, highVal, vY, rollOffWidth=rollOffWidth)",
    number=10_000,
    globals=globals(),
)

t2 = timeit(
    "GenSmoothStep2(vX, lowVal, highVal, vY, rollOffWidth=rollOffWidth)",
    number=10_000,
    globals=globals(),
)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints on my computer (AMD 5700X):

```py
0.010718749952502549
0.007840660051442683
```

So the new function is ~36% faster.

Comment: I thought about such solution, yet it adds memory allocations which I'd like to avoid. This is the reason I used loop. +1. I also think it won't allow to choose the width of the roll off.

Comment: @Royi, it's also slower that your current numba version

Comment: @Royi I've updated my answer.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Sorry, I don't follow - it still faster even if I swap the order of calls (first `t2`, then `t1`)

Comment: @AndrejKesely, it's not about the order, think of " in separate runs, not one by one in single flow". Run one `timeit` at one time (get the time amount), then rerun with another `timeit` for another function. I've also fell for that trick when I wanted to post my version which was 3X faster, but that wasn't true

Comment: @AndrejKesely, skip/remove the preceding "warm up" calls for the above runs

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That's needed, because I want to first let `numba` compile the functions. I did other perf test with `perfplot`. Still, my function is faster.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, Understood. I just thought about cases/applications where such function is supposed to be called once on a big input (like `numGridPts = 1000_000`), warming up in that cases seems to be an overhead.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, that's one "drawback" of `numba` (it needs to first compile the functions). One can use ahead-of-time compilation, caching or just call it before "real" work starts (with some small parameters). Calling numba function once it's usually not worth (the compilation will kill the performance).

Comment: With pre-running your function goes faster, yes.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, There is an edge case my code takes care of which is missing. For instance, set `highVal = 1.0`. A division by zero will be generated.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, This is how I fixed it: https://imgur.com/XBmyCPA. Just used a switch case for the edge values.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, See my update. If one takes care of the edge cases, then performance difference are negligible. Any other idea?